# Blender bouncing ball calculation

Tags: python, blender

I am trying to make a script thats animating a bouncing basket ball in blender-

Keyfactors are

- Ball diameter: 25cm
- Falling height: 1.7m
- Velocity 0.8m / s

After each boink (hitting the floor) it should only have 85% of its velocity and 77% of its height.

My code so far

```
# Variablen# Variablen
h = 1.7         # height
g = 9.81        
t = 0           # time

v0 = 0.8       # velocity m / s

ctx.scene.frame_current = 1
ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location')

s = v0 * t     # distance on x

boinks = 9

for x in range(1, boinks + 1):

    t = t+math.sqrt(2*h/g)
    s = t * v0

    ctx.scene.frame_current = t*24
    ops.transform.translate(value=(s, 0, -h))
    ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location')

    ctx.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'                      
    ops.graph.select_leftright(mode='RIGHT')    
    ops.graph.handle_type(type='VECTOR')                
    ctx.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'

    v0 = v0*0.85
    h = h * 0.77
    t = t+math.sqrt(2*h/g)
    s = t * v0

    ctx.scene.frame_current = t*24
    ops.transform.translate(value=(s, 0, h))
    ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location')

    ctx.area.type = 'GRAPH_EDITOR'                      
    ops.graph.select_leftright(mode='RIGHT')    
    ops.graph.handle_type(type='FREE')
    ctx.area.type = 'TEXT_EDITOR'
```

But it's looking somehow wrong. I think I am missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, i'm not so sure if this will help you, but with the location fcurve selected for your object, you can press **T** and select *bounce*, so you've done.
It's quite unuseful if you want to make a code with parameters, but as a starting point, it fits quite well.